# How to check that object of type `Any` is an array of concrete class implementing some protocol

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I have faced an issue.
Consider I have one protocol and two classes implementing it:

```
protocol Initiatable{
    init()
}

class A: Initiatable{
    required init() {}
}

class B: Initiatable{
    required init() {}
}
```

then at some point I'm creating an array and passing it to function:

```
var array = [A]()

func update(object: Any){

}

update(object: array)
```

from that function `update` I would like to pass `object` to another function if it mets another function's conditions:

```
func process<T: Initiatable>(array: T){
    /* ... */
}
```

So how can I check that object of type `Any` is an array of concrete class implementing `Initiatable` protocol? I would like to write something like

```
func update(object: Any){
    if let array = object as Array<T: Initiatable>{
        process(array: array)
    }
}
```

But that's doesn't work. Code like:

```
func update(object: Any){
    if let array = object as [Initiatable]{
        process(array: array)
    }
}

func process(array: [Initiatable]){ }
```

Compiles fine, but that's not what I want – `process` function should receive an array of concrete implementation of `Initiatable` so at some point it could use:

```
func process<T: Initiatable>(array: [T]){
    /* other code */
    T.init()
}
```

So is there any way to do this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I've also had problems with this kind of thing when dealing with generics. Is there a reason to not have a second version of update like `func update<T: Initiatable >update(object: [T])`?

Comment: Once you've called `T.init()`, what could you possibly do with it? There are no methods you could call on it, so what can `process` actually do? The only thing you know is that it can be constructed using `init()`. There's a reason `Initiatable` doesn't exist in the stdlib. It wasn't an accidental omission. https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/protocols-have-semantics/ There are a lot of concerning patterns here (starting with passing `Any`). This kind of generic/reflection code tends to be very fragile even if you get it working. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: The code in example above is just a simplification of what I'm working with. Of course `Initiatable` have other functions in my code (and also have a different name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to solve this problem:

```
func classTypeFrom(_ className: String) -> AnyClass!{
    if  let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as? String {
        let classStringName = "_TtC\(appName.characters.count)\(appName)\(className.characters.count)\(className)"
        return NSClassFromString(classStringName)
    }
    return nil;
}

func update(object: Any){
    if let array = object as? [Initiatable]{
        let arrayTypeName = "\(type(of: ar))"
        let objectTypeName = arrayTypeName.substringFrom(index: 6, length: arrayTypeName.characters.count - 7)
        if let arrayType = classTypeFrom(objectTypeName) as? Initiatable.Type{
            process(array: array, type: arrayType)
        }
    }
}

func process(array: [Initiatable], type: Initiatable.Type){
    var ar = array
    let newObj = type.init()
    ar.append(newObj)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a few parts to this question:

**Generating the array of types**

Your array declaration is expecting an array of `A` *objects* rather than `A` *types*. To generate an array with A types, you could pass in a Postfix `self` expression:  ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID455))

```
var array = [ A.self ]
```

This would define `array` as an array of `A.Type`, called the Metatype Type ([same link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID455)).

You could also generate an empty array with this metatype type:

```
var array:[A.Type] = []
```

If you wanted an array with both `A.self` and `B.self` you could either specify it as `[Any]`...

```
var array:[Any] = [A.self,B.self]
```

...or, make use of the `Initiatable` protocol you created:

```
var array:[Initiatable.Type] = [A.self,B.self]
```

**Downcasting an array to an array of types in your update method**

You were having trouble downcasting an Any object to an array of types. 
Here's my updated `update` method:

```
func update(object: Any){
  if let array = object as? [Initiatable.Type] {    //1
    process(array: array)
  }
}
```

1. You can now perform an optional downcast on the array that is being past into your `update` method. Downcast it to an array of metadata types of `Initiatable`: (This is the only line I modified from your method)

**Receiving a type as a parameter in the process method**

I'm assuming that you just want your process method to receive an array of types, and instantiate a variable based on one of those types. You didn't mention which element in the array, so I've just gone with the first.

```
func process(array: [Initiatable.Type]){    //1
  if let firstType = array.first {          //2
    let firstObject = firstType.init()      //3
  }
}
```

1. The `process` method can receive an array of types that adopt the Initiatable protocol.
2. I'm using optional binding to get at the value of the first element in the array. This should be a type.
3. Instantiate an object based on the first element in the array.

Comment: Thank you for a such detailed answer! Unfortunately that's not what I am looking for. The array MUST be array of concrete type (I can't use array of types like in your answer) and it is empty (in your answer it's filled with object types). The whole idea is that I would like to check object of kind `Any` and if it is array, to fill it with objects of it type.

Comment: In my answer I show instantiating the array 4 ways, one of which creates an empty array. Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by concrete type? I assumed you were meaning the definition of a class/struct/enum as a concrete type (as opposed to an abstract type, such as a definition of a protocol). But perhaps you were just meaning an object / instance?

Comment: In all of your ways you are creating array of object types, so array's type is either `[A.Type]` or `[Initiatable.Type]`. In my question (and it is required) array should be array of concrete objects, like `[A]` or `[B]`.

Comment: Ah - ok, I was misunderstanding - rather than concrete types/classes (eg. A.Type) you want the array to be of objects (eg. A), got it. I think I was confused by calling the init method in the process method, and assumed you wanted to instantiate an object at that point from a type. When you say in your question "Compiles fine, but that's not what I want" - what exactly was the problem with that code? (other than the missing optional unwrapping)

Comment: The problem is that with signature like `process(array: [Initiatable])` I couldn't create instances of array's objects type in it. Of course I couldn't write `Initiatable.init()`. And consequently I want a stricter restriction for `array`, so only arrays of `[A]` or `[B]` could be passed to this function.

Comment: I'm a bit lost - if the function definition is `process(array: [Initiatable])`, you *can* pass in an array of [A] if you like, or an array of [B]. When you say 'stricter' and 'only' - do you mean you don't want a mixture of both A and B in an array to be passed to the function? Or do you mean you don't want any other arrays that also implement the Initiatable protocol? I guess i need to know - what do you NOT want to be passed to the function?

Answer (score 1):

If your array is nonempty, then you can solve this by grabbing the runtime type of one element from the array:

```
func update(object: Any){
    if let array = object as? [Initiatable]{
        process(array: array)
    } else {
        // Not initiatable
    }
}

func process(array: [Initiatable]) {  // no need for generics here
    guard let first = array.first else {
        // Unable to determine array type
        // throw or return or whatever
    }

    // type(of: first) gives A or B
    type(of: first).init()
}
```

If the array is empty, then I don’t know of a way to do this in Swift (as of Swift 3, anyway).

- The static type of `object` is `Any`, so you need to use the *runtime* type of `object` in order to get anywhere.
- However, Swift (and most languages with generics) only resolve type parameters like `T` based on the *static* types of the values you pass. Therefore your whole approach with `process<T: Initiatable>(array: [T])` is a dead end: `T` can only take on *a type the compiler already knew* when you called `process()`.
- Swift does give you access to runtime types: `type(of: object)` will return (for example) `Array<A>`. So close! But:

  - AFAIK, there is currently no way to extract type parameters from a metatype, i.e. to get `A` from `Array<A>`, unless the compiler already knows the type parameter statically.
  - You *can* get the string `"Array<A>"` and extract the string `A` from it, but AFAIK there is no way to map strings back to types in Swift unless the type is an Objective-C class.

In short, I think you’ve just hit a limit of Swift’s metatype / reflection capabilities.

Comment: Despite your answer has provided a solution, it was the only one to guide my thinking in the correct direction so I'm rewarding you for helping!

Comment: Well, thanks! And I won’t be offended if you switch the accepted answer to somebody else if they figure out a trick to make it work.

Comment: P.S. It’s _conceivable_ that the type system improvements coming in Swift 4 will make this possible. Swift 4 will add existentials, which would all `process(…)` to accept something like `Array where Element: Initiatable` (but the runtime type of `Element` is still unknown to the compiler). You then might be able to do `type(of: array).Element.self.init()`. I don’t think this is possible in Swift 3 without the existential type, though.

Comment: I've posted the solution, you can check it out :)

Comment: Cool. Did you have to mark your classes `@objc` and/or extend `NSObject` to make that work? I’d ruled out anything involving `NSClassFromString` for that reason (per the very last bullet point).

Comment: No, it's not necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't think of a solution in a given constraints. It seems like you are trying to achieve compile-time polymorphism at runtime.

Using generics implies that compiler understands what class will be called. But using `Any` implies that at compile time it could be anything and it would be known only at runtime.

The closest solutions that I can propose are:

```
// Either use generic `update` function
func updateGeneric<T: Initiatable>(array: Array<T>){
    process(array: array)
}

// or explicitly convert `Any` to the class, 
// so compiler understands what implementation of `process` to call
func updateExplicit(object: Any) {

    if let array = object as? [A] {
        process(array: array)
    }

    if let array = object as? [B] {
        process(array: array)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this help you,

```
protocol Initiatable{
    init()
}

class A: Initiatable{
    required init() {}
}

class B: Initiatable{
    required init() {}
}

class Test<T : Initiatable>
{

    func update(object: Any){
        if let array = object as? [T]{
            process(array: array)
        }
    }

    func process(array: [T]){

    }
}
```